Draggable Items Disappear or Misalign When Dropped in FullCalendar with StimulusJS in Rails
I am integrating FullCalendar with StimulusJS in a Ruby on Rails application to build an interactive scheduling tool. Most of it works as expected, but I am encountering an issue with draggable events when moving them over the calendar.
The Problem:
When I drag and move a draggable event over the calendar field, the dragged element disappears (changes to display: none according to the DOM inspection).
Even if I force the element to remain visible, it doesn't update its position correctly and stays outside the calendar fields.
Below are the key code snippets that highlight my current setup:
FullCalendar Setup:
setupCalendar = () => {
    this.calendar = new Calendar(this.timelineWrapperTarget, {
        plugins: [interactionPlugin, luxonPlugin, resourceTimelinePlugin],
        initialView: 'resourceTimeline',
        initialDate: DateTime.now().startOf('week').toISODate(),
        droppable: true,
        drop: async (eventData) => {
            const templateData = camelcaseKeys(
                JSON.parse(eventData.draggedEl.dataset.calendarEntry), 
                { deep: true }
            );

            let calendarEntryType = templateData.templateType === "shift" ? "shifts" : "absences";
            const requestBody = decamelizeKeys({
                date: eventData.dateStr,
                contractFunctionId: eventData.resource.id,
                templateId: templateData.templateId,
            }, { deep: true });

            // API call for Shifts
            if (calendarEntryType === "shifts") {
                await post(`/${window.currentWorkspaceSlug}/employee_zone/work_schedule/shifts.json`, {
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    body: requestBody,
                });
                this.calendar.refetchEvents();
            }
        },
    });
}


Draggable Items Setup:
setupDraggableItems = () => {
    new Draggable(document.getElementById('shift-and-absence-template-list'), {
        itemSelector: '.draggable-item',
    });
}


CSS Workaround:

The dragged element changes to display: none after dragging inside the calendar fields.
I forced the visibility using:

.fc-event-dragging {
    display: block !important;
}


While this makes the event visible again, it remains stuck outside the calendar and does not align with the drop location.

I need some advice. How can i fix the draggable events? It just keeps disappearing within the calendar

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
